# Как работает RSA в C#?

Tags: rsa

День добрый, тов. программисты.
Пытаюсь сделать приложение для RSA шифрования, но не могу понять одной вещи.

В `RSACryptoServiceProvider` явно задаю длину ключа, где `byteLenRSAKeys = 2048`

```
rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(byteLenRSAKeys);
// Экспортирую ключи        
privateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
```

В дальнейшем выясняется, что фактическая длина ключа другая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

256 * 2 + 128 * 5 = 1152

Создаю 2048, а по факту 1152. Кто может объяснить? Я что-то делаю не так или дело в самом `RSACryptoServiceProvider`?

Comment: Кажется, я понял в чём проблема. В конструкторе RSACryptoServiceProvider(int dwKeySize) указано, что dwKeySize задаётся в битах, а не байтах.

Тогда получается всё верно. Задаём 2048 битов - получаем закрытый (D) и открытый (Modulus) ключи по 256 байтов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не все приведенные составляющие являются часть ключа. Насколько я помню. Размер влияет только на `Modulus`, т.е. вы указали 2048 бит, то у вас он и будет равен 256 * 8 = 2048.

- `Exponent` это некое простое число, часто его берут как 65537.
- `P` и `Q` два простых числа, на основании которых будут высчитываться другие числа, в том числе и `Modules`, размер этих чисел обычно берется как половина ключа.
- `D`, `DP`, `DQ` - разные экспоненты.
- `InverseQ` - коэфициент.

Публичный ключ состоит `Modules` и `Exponent`.
Приватный - из всего что перечислено выше, но напрямую это не зависит от ключа, эти все поля нужны, чтобы каждый раз и не рассчитывать заново, т.к. в теории будет хватать только `P`, `Q`, `Exponent`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, я так и понял свою ошибку. Просто был сбит с толку тем, что задаёшь размер ключа 2048 бит, получаешь данных на 1152 байт. И по итогу, расшифровать в RSACryptoServiceProvider можно только используя все 1152 байта